# Is it possible to use `.*` in SystemVerilog to register interfaces' elements?

Tags: system-verilog

Let's say I have one interface, I'd like to

```
interface myIf;
  logic a;
  logic b;
  logic c;
  logic d;
  logic e;
  logic f;
endinterface

interface mypartIf;
  logic b;
  logic c;
  logic d;
endinterface

module top (
  input clk,
  myIf interf
)

  mypartIf part();

  always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    part.* <= interf.*; // should match b,c,d names in both interfaces
  end
endmodule
```

Of course this example doesn't work.

I could replace `mypartIf` with a `struct` and register the `struct` but in that case I'll have a different namespace.

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic b;
  logic c;
  logic d;
} mypartIf;

interface myIf;
  logic a;
  mypartIf othernamespace;   // HERE
  logic e;
  logic f;
endinterface

module top (
  input clk,
  myIf interf
)

  mypartIf part;

  always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    part <= interf.othernamespace; // This should work
  end
endmodule
```

I would like to make it as simple as possible, name matching would be a good solution without adding `struct`. Moreover adding `struct` doesn't allow me to use crossing fields.

What is the best practices to use crossing elements like this ?

Comment: Ambiguous title did not state 'SystemVerilog', downvoting. Have corrected title for benefit of other users.

Comment: really ? now we need to indicate it in a tag AND in the title ? come on..

Comment: Easy. The idea of the question title is to attract the sort of people who can help you. In the questions list, you see the title clearly but the tags less so and many don't read/filter them. The website covers a very broad range of electronics design topics so people may find it a cryptic title. Look at the clarity in some of the other question titles. The idea is to help yourself help people to help you? I have to put time into making my own answers unambiguous. It doesn't sound exhausting to write 'SystemVerilog' in the title.

Comment: Then why downvote? Nothing's wrong if I don't specify it in the title, it was pretty clear. Anyway, different rules than in stackoverflow.

Comment: It wasn't remotely clear, I'm afraid, and it's such a simple change to ask for. Clear questions get better answers wherever you go. Anyway, there it is and good luck in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t do this. An `interface` only helps you collect a group of signals and make connections to other ports as a group. You still need to access all the signals individually inside the module as if they were separate ports.

If you want to access the values as a group use the `struct`.  Just make sure you put the `typedef` for the `struct` in a common `package`. Then you will not have a namespace issue.